# Objective C : Assertion Failure when reading data from database

Tags: objective-c, database, sqlite, nsstring, assertion

I am using the functions describes [HERE](https://github.com/anthonyly/SQLiteManager) to access an sqlite database.
I am having issue with the function:

> -(NSArray *)find:(NSString *)field from:(NSString *)table where:(NSString *)condition.

This function works well for when the condition is nil and when the condition is a string without any format or method; ie it works well when  it is either of the following

> NSArray *result = [[SQLiteManager singleton] find:@"field1,field2" from:@"tableName" where:nil];
>
> NSArray *result = [[SQLiteManager singleton] find:@"field1,field2" from:@"tableName" where:@"field2=value"];

However, I have a condition that should read from a UITextField.  for example

> NSArray *result = [[SQLiteManager singleton] find:@"field1,field2" from:@"tableName" where:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"field3=%@",[textFieldName text]]];

Unfortunately, the code breaks when I try this giving me an *Assertion Failure* error. ANy reason why? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least you probably want to put single quotes around your `%@`. Like this:

```
NSArray *result = [[SQLiteManager singleton] find:@"field1,field2"
 from:@"tableName" where:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"field3='%@'",
 [textFieldName text]]];
```

But in addition to that you may also want to escape the string.